# Find the micro-organism growth after a certain amount of minutes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, biology

For an experiment,

I put in a cell growing medium, 1 bacterium of type A and 3 bacteria of type B and every minute I add 1 bacterium of type A and 3 bacteria of type B. So, after 1 minute it means that my cell growing medium will contains 6 bacteria of type A and 9 bacteria of type B. Both bacteria grows at different speed.

The first bacterium of type A is growing at $A(t) = 4t+1$
The second bacterium of type B is growing at $B(t) = 2^t$

I am trying to figure the total amount of bacteria I will have after 5 minutes.

Just to sum up what I have so far:

- For A:

  - t = 0, $[A]$
  - t = 1, $4*1+1=5$ then I add $1$, $6$
  - t = 2, $4*6+1=25$ then I add $1$, $26$
  - t = 3, $4*26+1=105$ then I add $1$, $126$
- For B:

  - t = 0, $[BBB]$
  - t = 1, $2^3=8$ -- not valid
  - t = 2, can't figure that one.

I'm really curious to see the answer and how to solve this kind of problem.

Thanks

Comment: Huh? You write that every minute you add 1 bacterium of type A, and you write that type A is growing according to $4t+1$, and you write that A becomes AAAAAA after one minute. These three are all different. You have to figure out which of these you really mean, first.

Comment: The singular is "bacterium", the plural is "bacteria".

Comment: And what is $x$ in all of this?  $B(t) = 2^x$ ?  I will try decipher this question but I will also agree with the others that it needs to be rewritten.

Comment: Where does the $11$ come from in $2^{11}$?

Comment: I have rephrased the problem, I hope it's better now, sorry.

Comment: You *still* have adding $1$, growing as $4t+1$, and AAAAAA as if they are all the same thing, when they are all different. Your question does not even begin to make sense. Please think it through, decide what you really mean, and then write it clearly, correctly, and unambiguously. If it takes you a few days to figure out how, no worries, math is eternal.

Comment: Sorry - I'm clarifying it as much as I can right now, English not being my native language, I'm doing my best. Thanks.

Comment: There is a big difference between $A(t)=4t+1$, which is already solved and $A(t)=4A(t-1)+1$.  Neither corresponds to $A(1)=6$.  In the first, we would have $A(2)=9$, in the second $A(2)=21$

Comment: It's not your english that is the problem, it's the numbers, they don't check out.  Can you do a worked calculation (including every step) for times $t=0, t=1, t=2, t=3$?  That way, we can see what exactly you are doing

Comment: More information added.

Comment: I'm going to need many more minutes to solve this.

Comment: @FrancisLacoste Have a look at my answer and see if this satisfies you.

Comment: If it doesn't satisfy you, perhaps also explain the mechanism by which each of these bacteria grow.  I find it rather weird any bacteria would grow like $B(t) = 2^t B(t-1)$, something more common would be $B(t) = 2B(t-1)$.

Comment: muzzlator, Thanks a lot, I will check it out tomorrow morning, it's really late here. Oh and before I forget, what software are you using to calculate recursive function ? WolframAlpha seems to have some problem with these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your numbers at $1$ and $2$ minutes, you really have $A(n+1)=4A(n)+1$ and $B(n+1)=2^{B(n)}$ with $A(0)=1, B(0)=3$.  You should follow each chain separately as they don't interact.  The number of $B$'s is then $B(t)=(2\uparrow \uparrow(t-1))^3$.  The $A$'s are a [linear recurrence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recursive_sequence#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients)  The [up-arrow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) is a chain of exponentials, one taller each stage.

Comment: You might have to explain the up-arrow notation to OP (and me).

Comment: Isn't a single $\uparrow$ just exponentiation?

Comment: @GerryMyerson:  good point.  I have added a reference.

Comment: Seems you perhaps want a $\uparrow \uparrow$ if you want a single power tower.

Comment: @muzzlator:  correct.  fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with new data values in mind:

You mean $A(t) = 4 A(t-1) + 1$ is how they grow, and then you add $1$, so in fact $$A(t) = 4A(t-1) + 2$$

Similarly, $$B(t) = 2^t B(t-1) + 3$$

This gives $B(1) = 9$ and $B(2) = 39$, not $2051$.

Solving the recurrence relationships gives:

$$ A(t) = \frac{5}{3} 4^t - \frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{3} \left(5 \cdot 4^t - 2\right)$$

I have seen the explicit solution for $B(t)$ using Mathematica and it isn't pretty.  You'd be better off just looking at the recurrence equation but anyway...

$$ B(t) = 2^{\frac{1}{2} \left(t^2+t-2\right)} \left(\sum _{k=0}^{t-1} 3\ 2^{-\frac{1}{2}k(k+3)}+6\right) $$